# Add one or two pictures to the jQuery Slider

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to add a jQuery slider to my website and I found this one met my requirement. But the slider just show 3 pictures, how to add one or two other pictures to the slider?

Demo: [http://d.lanrentuku.com/down/js/jiaodiantu-883/](http://www.lanrentuku.com/js/jiaodiantu-883.html)

The html code

```
<div id="preview-slider">
    <div id="preview-slide-1" style="display: none;"><a target="_blank" href="http://www.lanrentuku.com/"><img width="930" height="300" alt="" src="images/01.jpg"></a></div>
    <div class="preview-hide" id="preview-slide-2" style="display: block;"><a target="_blank" href="http://www.lanrentuku.com/"><img width="930" height="300" alt="" src="images/02.jpg"></a></div>
    <div class="preview-hide" id="preview-slide-3" style="display: none;"><a target="_blank" href="http://www.lanrentuku.com/"><img width="930" height="300" alt="" src="images/03.jpg"></a></div>
    <div id="preview-slider-line">
        <ul id="preview-slider-holder">
            <li class="preview-first">
                <div class="preview-slider-thumbnail"><a target="_blank" href="http://www.lanrentuku.com/"><img width="66" height="36" id="preview-thumbnail-im1" alt="" src="images/01.png" style="top: 0px;"></a></div>
                <span><a target="_blank" href="http://www.lanrentuku.com/">Picture 1</a></span></li>
            <li class="preview-second">
                <div class="preview-slider-thumbnail"><a target="_blank" href="http://www.lanrentuku.com/"><img width="66" height="36" id="preview-thumbnail-im2" alt="" src="images/02.png" style="top: -15px;"></a></div>
                <span><a target="_blank" href="http://www.lanrentuku.com/">Picture 2</a></span></li>
            <li class="preview-third">
                <div class="preview-slider-thumbnail"><a target="_blank" href="http://www.lanrentuku.com/"><img width="66" height="36" id="preview-thumbnail-im3" alt="" src="images/03.png" style="top: 0px;"></a></div>
                <span><a target="_blank" href="http://www.lanrentuku.com/">Picture 3</a></span></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

The javascript code

```
    (function($){
            $(document).ready(function() {
                    var ready = true, position = 1, timer = null, domer = $('ul#preview-slider-holder > li');
                    var anima = function () {
                            if (!ready) {
                                    $("#preview-slider > div:not(':last'):not(':eq(" + position + ")')").each(function(){
                                            if($(this).is(':animated')){
                                                    $(this).stop(true, true);
                                            }                              
                                    });                              
                            }
                            ready = false;
                            $("#preview-slider > div:not(':last'):not(':eq(" + position + ")')").hide();
                            $('img', this).animate({"top": "-15px"}, 200);
                            $('#preview-slide-' + (position + 1)).fadeIn(600, function(){
                                    ready = true;
                            });
                            $('img[id^="preview-thumbnail-im"]:not([id="preview-thumbnail-im' + (position+1) + '"])').stop(true, false).animate({'top': '0px'}, 200);
                            position = ++ position % 3;
                    };
                    timer = setInterval(function(){anima.apply(domer)}, 2000); // interval time
                    domer.mouseover(function () {
                            timer == null || clearInterval(timer);               
                            if($(this).hasClass('preview-first')){
                                    position = 0;
                            } else if($(this).hasClass('preview-second')){
                                    position = 1;
                            } else if($(this).hasClass('preview-third')){
                                    position = 2;
                            }
                            anima.apply(this);
                   });
                   domer.mouseout(function () {
                            timer = setInterval(function(){anima.apply(domer)}, 2000);   
                   });
            });
    })(jQuery);
```

I tried to add a li element , but it didn't work. I think I need to modify the javascript code. But I am not good at the programming, will someone tell how to do?

Comment: There are dozens of good image sliders / carousels out there that handle unlimited images. Why are you sticking with this thing?

Comment: DevlshOne, I have checked some amazing sliders and found they could NOT work in IE6, so I had to chose this slider. Most people in China are still surfing the web via IE6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I agree with DevlshOne, that many other quality sliders are out there. To answer the OP's question, you have to fix the code to not have hard-coded positions. Instead, I chose to use the index method present with jQuery.

Here is the jsFiddle that shows 4 images working (though I used the original code, so no actual images are displayed).

http://jsfiddle.net/a5yqx/

The key changes to the code are from:

```
position = ++ position % 3;
...
if($(this).hasClass('preview-first')){
     position = 0;
} else if($(this).hasClass('preview-second')){
     position = 1;
} else if($(this).hasClass('preview-third')){
     position = 2;
}
```

To:

```
position = ++position % domer.length;
...
position = $(this).index();
```

Since I don't have the CSS to accompany it, I'm not sure what else you'll need to keep your style up, but good luck.

Last note, I changed the image size from your default to 10x10 in order to see it on my screen in the fiddle.

Comment: James, thank you very much. It works well. And I need to adjust the css for the new slider. I chose the slider because it could work in IE6 and some amazing sliders could NOT work in IE6. More than 20% people are using IE6 in China. It's very crazy.